# How to filter the Selection with LineWidth Catia VBA?

Tags: vba, catia

Is it possible to get all `Polyline` or `Curve2D` in drawing with LineWidth = something? It is possible with the color but when I tried `Selection.Search(".Curve.Thickness = 1")` or `Width` or `VisibleWidth` or `LineWidth`, none returns an error but results in no result also.

I could use loop, however, as I posted in another question, the speed is very low.

Comment: I guess you have to define the unit of the property. _Selection.Search "CAT2DLSearch.2DGeometry.Weight=0,35mm,all"_ works for me (depending on the decimal separator of the operating system?)

Comment: Or using the number of the defined line widths: _"CAT2DLSearch.2DGeometry.Weight:4,all"_

Comment: @Shrotter, thanks for the help. Yes, it is `Weight` and the `:4` does the trick.